# Set a TTImageView as background on a TTView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, coding-style, three20

Im having troubles to set a imagebackground on a TTView.
Here is the code i found on internet, but it only shows a black square.

```
- (TTView *) monthBar {
if (!_monthBar) {
    _monthBar = [[[TTView alloc] init] autorelease];
    _monthBar.style = TTSTYLE(calendarMonthBarStyle);
    _monthBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    TTImageView *imageView = [[TTImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 20)];  
    [imageView setDefaultImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"]];
    [self.monthBar addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
    [self addSubview: _monthBar];
}
return _monthBar;
}
```

If someone knows how to solve it, please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried UIImageView instead of TTImageView?

Answer (score 0):

Using an imageView as subview of `_monthBar` should normally not be necessary. You should instead use the image as background in the style. Your style seems to be called `calendarMonthBarStyle`. You'll need to add a TTImageStyle referencing "picture.png" there.